# magento Shipping prices not available during Checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, usps

Shipping Methods not available!
Hello,

I have a unique problem. I've 1.9.2.3 CE version. Some people say they can't proceed after entering their address. instead of getting their shipping methods (I use USPS), they get a message in place of the shipping methods that say "No shipping method available". The problem is that I go to the website and test it, and I see it fine.

I tried one and I had the same issue. I tried 10 min later, and it worked. What's the issue and how can I resolve it. I'm really a newbie here.

Thanks and I appreciate your time.

Comment: Please note that this issue have been reported by some people while others have no issues.

Comment: Is it easier to upgrade to version 2?